# Reading file line by line, and storing as a string

Tags: c++

In this program, I'm supposed to read the program line by line, and then use some functions that were given to me that will extract a portion of the string and send it to another function. I'm having a problem with reading the file and 'storing' th

```
void histogram(const int MaxPages, istream& input, ostream& output)
{
CountedLocation *array[MaxPages];
int linenum = 0;

string temp;
//getline(input, linestring);
//output << linestring;
while (linenum < MaxPages)
{
   string linestring = "";
   getline(input, linestring);
   //linenum++;
   extractTheRequest(linestring);
   if (isAGet(linestring) == true)
   {
       extractLocator(linestring);
       linenum++;
       output << linestring << endl;
       output << "test1";
   }
   linenum++;
}
```

The problem seems to be that the program never really "reads" the file. I tried having linestring initialized right below the initializion of string temp, as "string linestring = "f" ". The program would of course output the text file as several 'f's strung together. I tried looking on how to read it line by line, but the majority do not use istream, and I am not allowed to edit anything outside of the histogram function. Nothing in the if statement regarding "isAGet" ever really 'occurs'.

My problem is; how do I read the text file line by line, and then store each line into a string? I thought maybe I could just do it in a loop like I have below, storing the line into a temporary stream, doing what I need with it, and then clearing the stream to repeat the process. Is there another approach that would be easier? I can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: so what is isAGet? And are you sure the file opened?

Comment: isAGet is a bool that checks whether or not the string parsed to it has a certain set of characters in it ('GET'). And I'm fairly certain the file is open when the program runs. The histogram function is located in histogram.cpp, but the program starts in counthits.cpp. I honestly do not understand how counthits counts, but in the main, it (presumably) takes the 3 parameters that are required when the program starts (maxPages, input file, output file), followed by the code (ifstream in (argv[2]); (ofstream out (argv[3]);) It then calls histogram, and then there's in.close and out.close.

Comment: When debugging, always try to isolate where the problem is.  Based on what you've said, the very first thing to do here is to comment out every line after `getline(input, linestring);` and before `linenum++;` and add a `cerr << linestring;` to check that it is actually reading the lines in the file.  Have you done this?

Comment: Your code isn’t valid C++ – you cannot declare a C-array in this fashion, you need to use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```
void histogram(const int MaxPages, istream& input, ostream& output) {
    if (!input.good()) {
        cerr << "File doesn't exist" << endl;
        return;
    }

    string line;
    for (int line_no = 0; getline(input, line); ++line_no) {
        output << '"' << line << '"' << endl;
    }
}
```

Mention those quotes put to console. They're to show that in case your file has an empty last line, `getline` will return an error, and `work_with_that_line` won't get called. It's a wide known problem with `getline`-style file input. In case you care, consider using char-by-char or binary input.

Comment: This would work normally, but I can't have a int main in this project; everything must be within the `void histogram` function. Additionally, we're not allowed to have the inclusions of <iostream> or <fstream>

Comment: In case you have some streams passed to your code, it shouldn't be a problem. Fixed my answer for that. Can you add a `<string>`?

Comment: <string> is preincluded, so yes. I can't declare another function though, so I wouldn't be able to create void work_with_that_line.

Comment: That's up to you to declare that function or not. Just write the code you need instead of the call to that function.

Comment: Ok, I tried implementing your code, and the program compiles, but regardless of what file I give it via the command parameters, it says that the file does not exist. Maybe it's something with the input stream. Histogram is given `istream& input`, I don't know if that helps. I don't understand file reading in general.

Comment: Could you show the code that reads the file and calls `histogram` function? (In case you don't want to edit your post, you can send it to `ideone.com` or `codepad.org`). I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere over there.

Comment: `if (!input.good())`: You can't assume that (given a result of `true`) the file failed to open. It could just be perhaps that a previous input operation reached the end-of-file. To be completely sure you should do `if (!input.is_open())`. Moreover, you can do the for loop as `for (std::string str; std::getline(input, str);) output << line;`

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's unlikely that there're any I/O operation in previous code. Looks like it's just a CS course assignment, where lecturer is teaching to use generic I/O. Doing `for` loop like that seems a good idea, but line numbers were used in topic starter's code for some reason (see that `MaxPages` constriant?).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your `isAGet` and `extractTheRequest` does but to answer *"how do I read the text file line by line, and then store each line into a string"*

Why not simply this ?

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
while ( std::getline(input, linestring) && (linenum < MaxPages ) )
{
  //...
  //Store into std::vector, if required
  vec.push_back(linestring); 

  //.. use other calls 
  output << linestring ;
  linenum++;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because "vector is not a member of 'std'". I should have included this in my question, but we're only given #include "histogram.h", #include "arrayUtils.h", and #include <string>. We can't add any more inclusions.

Comment: @JoJoBya _vector is not a member of 'std_ huh ?
Don't use vector then, process it within loop each `linestring`

Comment: I don't entirely understand. I declared string linestring, and then I added 
`while (std::getline(input, linestring) && (linenum < MaxPages))
{
output << "test";
}`
And there was no output written to the text file. If I were to add the line `output << "test2"` above the while loop, it displays, but not within the loop. I'm very confused, I **think** the file is already open, but I think my program is acting as if it isn't open.

Comment: Ignore the last part of my above comment. I tried doing just a while loop with only (linenum < MaxPages), and that displays fine. It's something with the getline conditional that's in that while statement that makes it not work. I don't think it's getting the line.

Comment: @JoJoBya okay so how are you calling your `histogram` ?. I guess your `input` stream is in bad state. Are your sure file can be read successfully with `input` ? Before calling `histogram`, try reading the `input` stream

Comment: I'm not allowed to alter anything outside of histogram. The project was given to me with a bunch of files already written; I'm only allowed to alter the histogram function. I tried creating a standalone `std::getline(input, linestring); output << input;` This causes the output text file to only display '0'. The second character of the input file is '0', so I'm not sure if it's displaying that, or if the 0 is due to some other factor.

Comment: Disregard my uncertainty over the '0'; I tried replacing the whole input file with just the letter 'a', and it still displays 0 in the output file.

Comment: @JoJoBya you're not helping by any means, you're repeating same thing again and again, no body has asked to put something unwanted/not allowed "stuff" for your project, all those check which I asked is just for debugging. If you can't debug your code a little bit, forget any help from SO. PS:  I just voted to close this question

Comment: I'm sorry, I just misunderstood what you were saying. I thought when you meant that I should try to edit how it was called in counthits, not try to read the input stream in histogram. I don't know why I read it that way, but I'm trying to debug now, it's just difficult for me since I don't really comprehend how the input stream works.